# How to hide REST API methods in LoopBack 2.0?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I haven't managed to hide API methods in LoopBack 2.0.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Exposing+models+over+a+REST+API#ExposingmodelsoveraRESTAPI-Hidingmethods), I should achieve this with something like:

```
var app = require('../app');
var Location = app.models.Location;
Location.deleteById.shared = false;
```

Howver, this doesn't seem to work.

Also, `console.log(Location.deleteById)` prints:

```
[Function]
```

If `deleteById` is a function and not an object, then the assignment to the `shared` property makes no sense. No surprise then, that `console.log(Location.deleteById.shared)` prints:

```
undefined
```

Any clues, anybody?

Comment: See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/410

Answer (score 2):

You should see the new documentation,

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST#ExposingmodelsoverREST-HidingmethodsandRESTendpoints

this works for me,

```
MyModel.disableRemoteMethod('deleteById', true);
```

Comment: Just to point namely to description of several ways of method disabling - [Hiding methods and REST endpoints](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Exposing-models-over-REST.html#hiding-methods-and-rest-endpoints)